# Python regex positive lookbehind

Tags: python, regex

I have some multiline text that changes each time my python program is running. I want to search for an occurrence of a search pattern and then lookbehind to find the first line that starts with: `object-group network`

Example text (can be several thausands of lines long):

```
object-group network CISCO_ROUTER
 network-object host 1.1.1.1
 network-object object NCPVGW03_10.1.1.2
 network-object object NCPVGW04_10.1.1.3
 network-object object SGAVGW01_10.2.2.2
 network-object object NPLVGW02_10.1.6.2
 network-object object NCPVGW02_10.1.1.3
 network-object object C1121-8P_FGL2418L267_10.8.8.1
 network-object object NDEVGW01_10.6.4.2
 network-object object HD999901_192.168.0.3
 network-object object ISR4321-FDO21172C94_10.8.8.2
 network-object object DMRVGW02_10.1.1.4
object-group network CISCO_SWITCH
 network-object host 1.1.1.1
 network-object object HD138203_10.198.80.3
 network-object object HD165103_10.5.0.1
 network-object object HD166207_10.5.1.7
 network-object object HD134402_10.194.176.102
 network-object object HD137602_10.196.176.102
 network-object object HD131603_10.192.240.103
 network-object object HD134104_10.194.128.104
 network-object object HD166503_10.53.192.103
 network-object object HD165510_10.53.64.110
 network-object object HD202001_10.33.48.30
 network-object object HD132706_10.193.160.106
 network-object object HD700041_10.88.64.141
```

I want to find: `network-object object HD700041_10.88.64.141` and then the first occurrence of `object-group network` when i lookbehind.

I tried this regex search pattern: `(object-group network.+)[\w\W]+?(?<=HD700041_10\.88\.64\.141)`

But the result is: `object-group network CISCO_ROUTER`

How do I find the first occurrence `object-group network CISCO_SWITCH` when looking behind?

Comment: Why do you want it returned, if you already know exactly what it looks like and you just got confirmation that it was there (even though the regex doesn't yield it)?

Comment: I need the object group name for further processing.

Comment: And if, for some reason, you absolutely need for the regex to yield the value, why don't you just match the string itself, followed by a lookahead for the follow-up value?

Comment: I need to search for an object and see if it exists and then yield the group, where the object belongs to.

Comment: Ah, you need 'CISCO_ROUTER', gotcha - still, the second comment makes sense then? Why not use a lookahead, or just an expression matching both parts without lookahead/-behind?

Comment: No I need the CISCO_SWITCH group name, where the object belongs to. If you have an idea of a lookahead, please share, I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?m)^(object-group network.*)(?:\n(?!object-group).*)*\n.*HD700041_10\.88\.64\.141
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lnaJjb/2). *Details*:

- `(?m)^` - start of a line
- `(object-group network.*)`  - Group 1: the line with `object-group network`at the start
- `(?:\n(?!object-group).*)*` - zero or more lines that do not start with `object-group` string
- `\n` - a newline
- `.*HD700041_10\.88\.64\.141` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, and then `HD700041_10.88.64.141` text.

**Note** that `141` at the end may also match `141` in `141000`. Add `(?!\d)` at the end if you want to match specifically `141` value.